# Change column name from aggregate function default postgresql

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, alter-table

I created a (big) table like so:

```
create table names_and_pics as (
    select e.emp_name, e.dept, max(p.prof_pic)
    from e.employees
    left join profiles p
      on e.emp_id = p.emp_id )

select * from names_and_pics;

emp_name | dept | max(p.prof_pic)
Dan      | IT   | 1234.img 
Phil     | HR   | 3344.img 
...
```

Because I forgot to give the 3rd field a name, I need to rename it now to "img_link" The syntax I've been trying is

`alter table names_and_pics rename max(p.prof_pic) to img_link;`

That gives the following error:

> Syntax Error at or near "("

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Run in psql `\d names_and_pics` to figure the actual column name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the column names in double quotes because it contains invalid characters:

```
alter table names_and_pics rename "max(p.prof_pic)" to img_link;
```

More about quoted identifiers in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

---

<sup>Btw: the parentheses around the select in your `create table ... as select` statement are useless noise</sup>